# Taxation of capital gains on leveraged ETFs

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, leveraged-etf

Are capital gains on leveraged ETFs in the USA given a tax treatment different from the tax treatment given to capital gains on stocks? Leveraged ETFs use derivatives to generate their returns, and derivatives are taxed differently from equity or fixed-income instruments. So leveraged ETFs might not have the same tax efficiencies as do other funds. Also, they are treated as 1256 style contracts.

Comment: Is there something specific about leveraged ETFs that makes you think there should be different tax treatment?

Comment: Please see edit.